# Can I crop an image by its content in php (imagick)?

Tags: php, imagick

I have a transparent PNG image of a signature and I need to extract the signature from it (while removing unused space from the edges).

[image: Illustration]

I had an idea to find actual signature dimensions using loops and `getImagePixelColor` to scan image pixel by pixel from each side to find distance between edge and first non-transparent pixel. However this solution involves writing lots of repetitive code (4 almost same loops) and (I believe) is very inefficient.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like its *supposed* to take 4 loops since a crop to content by definition is on all four rectangular sides. ... Do you not want to do it?

Comment: And you might not need to write "lots of repetitive code" if you write the code to be reusable.

Comment: You only need to iterate once over all pixels to find the extrema in both dimensions.

Comment: Good observation @Peter. But the "four" loops way could be optimized to exclude pixel ranges from the previous loop's finding, and thus would always be faster than examining every pixel.